How to recycle both function and it's JSDoc in a class definition?
I'm cracking my head over this...
I know I can recycle/reuse both function and it's documentation by defining them on a class then extending another class... But this way will block inheriting from the class I want...
class Base
{
   /**
    * #1
    */
   reclyclable ()
   {
      // ...
   }
}

// Then...
class Extension extends Base
{
}

// Both shows #1 docblock
Extension.recyclable;
Extension.recyclable();

// But this way Extension must always extends Base class
// instead of the class I really want.

This works just fine, but Extension must always extends Base instead of the class I really want.
/**
 * #1
 */
function recyclable ()
{
   // ...
}

/**
 * @borrows recyclable
 * - or -
 * @borrows recyclable as prototype.recyclable
 */
class Extension extends SomeUsefulClass
{
   recyclable = recyclable;
   // This is useful because when attaching, the `this` inside
   // `Extension.prototype.recyclable()` becomes `Extension.prototype`.
   // The same applies to `instance.recyclable()`:
   // `this` becomes `instance`.
}

Extension.prototype.recyclable; // shows no documentation
// but I want recyclable jsdoc showing at editor hinting...
Extension.prototype.recyclable(); // shows docblock #1

// Produces the same effects...
Extension.prototype.recyclable = recyclable;

It would be useful if we can do something like this (but it doesn't work):
class Extension extends SomethingUseful
{
    // attaching stuff in Extension.prototype
    {...this} = {recyclable, /* ... can add many functions*/};
    
    // attaching stuff in Extension class
    static {...this} = {recyclable, /* ... can add many functions*/};
    
    // If I do as follows I have to put a docblock in every
    // class that recycles the recyclable function...
    
    /**
     * #2
     */
    recyclable = recyclable;
    
}

Extension.prototype.recyclable; // shows docblock #2
Extension.prototype.recyclable(); // shows docblock #1

// I need both cases to show docblock #1 of the
// original recyclable function docblock...

